# Why do I get a deadlock?

Tags: java, multithreading, deadlock

I have a multithreading program, which sorts threads in order `strs` times. Every thread has its own monitor. One monitor of this thread (`lock`) and another monitor of the following thread (`unlock`) are passed to the constructor of each thread. First, when each thread starts, it must stop when `array[0] != this`, but if in I write this in line 13, the deadlock appears. So I use Threads.count, which is incremented every iterations. This way the program works. Could you tell me why this happens?

```
class Foo extends Thread
{
    private Object lock, unlock;
    Foo(Object lock, Object unlock)
    {
        this.lock = lock;
        this.unlock = unlock;
    }
    public void run()
    {
        synchronized(lock)
        {
            if(Threads.array[Threads.count] != this)    // line 13!!!
            {
                waiter();
            }
            for(int i = 0; i < Threads.strs; ++i)
            {
                if(Threads.array[0] == this)
                {
                    System.out.println(i+1);
                }
                System.out.print(getName() + ' ');
                ++Threads.count;
                if(Threads.array[Threads.thrs-1] == this)
                {
                    System.out.println();
                }
                if(unlock != lock)
                {
                    synchronized(unlock)
                    {
                        unlock.notify();
                    }
                    waiter();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    void waiter()
    {
        try
        {
            lock.wait();
        }
        catch(InterruptedException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }
}

public class Threads
{
    public static Thread array[];
    public static Object lock[];
    public static int count, strs, thrs;
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        thrs = 0;
        strs = 0;
        count = 0;
        try
        {
            assert(args.length == 2);
            thrs = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
            strs = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
            assert((thrs > 0) && (strs > 0));
        }
        catch(NumberFormatException | AssertionError e)
        {
            System.out.println("Uncorrect enter!");
            System.exit(1);
        }
        lock = new Object[thrs];
        array = new Thread[thrs];
        for(int i = 0; i < thrs; ++i)
        {
            lock[i] = new Object();
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < thrs; ++i)
        {
            if(i != thrs-1)
            {
                array[i] = new Foo(lock[i],lock[i+1]);
            }else
            {
                array[i] = new Foo(lock[i],lock[0]);
            }
            array[i].start();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You didn't tell us what Threads.array is. Is it atomic? Synchronized access? How is each object constructed? How is the last Foo constructed? Where are the locks coming from? Why are you notifying a locked mutex?

Comment: `Why are you notifying a locked mutex?`---perhaps because he prefers to do it correctly?

Comment: @BobDalgleish, I show you all code. Threads.array is array of threads in order. Array `lock[]` is array of monitors too in order. `One monitor of this thread (lock) and another monitor of the following thread (unlock) are passed to the constructor of each thread` as lock[i] and lock[i+1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Line 13 basically says "wait to get notified by a preceding thread, unless I am the first thread". Which makes sense: from what I can tell from the code, you want the threads to do their tasks one by one in the order that you have created the threads (which kind of defeats the purpose of using threads, but that is another story).

Also note that the program will not exit since all threads call `waiter()` at the end the loop.

So the solution is kind of straightforward: have all threads wait at the beginning of the loop, but after creating all threads, trigger the first thread to start running (which in turn will trigger the other threads to start running). Below a slightly adjusted copy of your code with the two changes I mentioned:

```
class ThreadsInSequence extends Thread
{
    private Object lock, unlock;
    ThreadsInSequence(Object lock, Object unlock)
    {
        this.lock = lock;
        this.unlock = unlock;
    }
    public void run()
    {
        synchronized(lock)
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < strs; ++i)
            {
                waiter();
                if(array[0] == this)
                {
                    System.out.println(i+1);
                }
                System.out.print(getName() + ' ');
                ++count;
                if(array[thrs-1] == this)
                {
                    System.out.println();
                }
                if(unlock != lock)
                {
                    synchronized(unlock)
                    {
                        unlock.notify();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    void waiter()
    {
        try
        {
            lock.wait();
        }
        catch(InterruptedException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }

    public static Thread array[];
    public static Object locks[];
    public static int count, strs, thrs;
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        thrs = 3;
        strs = 6;
        count = 0;
        locks = new Object[thrs];
        array = new Thread[thrs];
        for(int i = 0; i < thrs; ++i)
        {
            locks[i] = new Object();
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < thrs; ++i)
        {
            if(i != thrs-1)
            {
                array[i] = new ThreadsInSequence(locks[i],locks[i+1]);
            }else
            {
                array[i] = new ThreadsInSequence(locks[i],locks[0]);
            }
            array[i].start();
        }
        synchronized(locks[0]) {
            locks[0].notify();
        }
    }
}
```